# responsiveness in html and css @media query

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media, responsive-images

I'm trying to create 3 different scenario's. Small screen, medium screens and large screens.

```
  @media screen and (max-width: 400px)  {
      .message-large, .message-med { display: none; }
   }
  
  @media screen and (min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 1099px) {
      .message-large, .message-small { display: none; }
    }
  @media screen and (min-width: 1100px)  {  
    .message-small, .message-med { display: none; }
    }
```

The way it works as coded above, large scenario works on large display. medium scenario works on medium display. medium scenario works on small display <-- there is where the problem occurs.

```
<img class="message-small" src="message-small.png" width="1100" height="392" alt="Hover over this image or click on it to receive a PRO-TIP.">
    <p class="message-small">small</p>
<img class="message-med" src="message-med.png" width="1100" height="392" alt="Hover over this image or click on it to receive a PRO-TIP.">
    <p class="message-med">medium</p>
<img class="message-large" src="message-large.png" width="1100" height="392" alt="Hover over this image or click on it to receive a PRO-TIP.">
    <p class="message-large">large</p>
```

The p's are just to troubleshoot the issue. The img src width and height will be resized accordingly later on, haven't got that far yet.

Comment: Can you please create a code snippet so that we can analyze the issue as per the code it should work

Comment: Sorry, added it now.

Comment: I cross checked your code, Everything seems to work fine :) Please check again

Comment: Exactly  as @ImranRafiqRather mention, everything is working as expected. [Link](https://codepen.io/vicky86/pen/LYRNrmw)

Comment: OMG I overlooked the obvious... thanks guys. Browser on desktop can't resize to below 400px even on smallest window, had to use mobile view in console. Thanks again!